# Cannot access (or ping) a particular website (buxfer.com) from Amazon Workspace Linux Desktop

Tags: ping, firewall

As title, I am exploring remote desktop using Amazon Workspace. As a newbie, I started a virtual machine using the Amazon Linux as the operating system, things are working well when I access sites like google. But when I try to access buxfer.com, it shows only a blank page.

I narrowed down the possible issue by doing the following:

- both firefox and chrome browser cannot access buxfer.com
- I use my own desktop at home and can access buxfer.com
- I used tunnelbear to create a VPN in the Amazon Workspace machine but still buxfer.com cannot be accessed
- I tried pinging buxfer.com in Amazon Workspace machine and found that buxfer.com cannot be pinged
- I tried pinging the IP behind buxfer.com and found that the IP cannot be ping also
- I used `iptable -F` to flush everything in the firewall, yet still cannot access buxfer.com

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Have you opened a case with AWS support?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it using my "home" connection and using a tunnel via a datacenter (hetzner.de). Seems as if buxfer.com blocks connections from known datacenter IP-ranges (HTTP 403 Forbidden). Normally that is done to prevent bot-access to their website. Don't think you can do anything about it...